# Oracle : How to GROUP and ORDER in a single Query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

There is a table : FRUIT, the content :

```
NAME
------
Banana
Orange
Orange
Apple
Banana
Apple
Apple
Apple
```

I want result like this (Grouped and Ordered):

```
NAME
----
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

I created a query :

```
SELECT NAME
FROM FRUIT
ORDER BY NAME
GROUP BY NAME
```

I think it will run weel in MySql or Foxpro. But not in Oracle. How do I should the query like ? Thanks

Comment: What did you try and what was the error?

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 1

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM FRUIT
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME
```

You could then use distinct if to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try this as well since you need only a single column to be displayed -

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM FRUIT
ORDER BY NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

try it out

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM FRUIT ORDER BY NAME;
```

this query returns unique NAME with order by NAME..